# Where is the documentation for Spamhaus?

Tags: email-spam, spam-prevention

I would like to know how to query Spamhaus for IP addresses (Spamhaus zen http://www.spamhaus.org/zen/) and for domains (DBL http://www.spamhaus.org/dbl/) found in incoming email in order to determine whether a given message is spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interface to the DBL through `host` or `dig`, since it runs as a DNS service. This page of the FAQ shows example queries: http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/Spamhaus%20DBL#277

```
$ host example.com.dbl.spamhaus.org
Host example.com.dbl.spamhaus.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

$ host dbltest.com.dbl.spamhaus.org
dbltest.com.dbl.spamhaus.org has address 127.0.1.2
```

IP address lookups are done similarly, with the numbers in the IP address in reverse order (`1.2.3.4` becomes `4.3.2.1.zen.spamhaus.org`). This is documented at the bottom of the FAQ for DNSBL (http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage#252).

```
$ host 130.119.180.199.zen.spamhaus.org
130.119.180.199.zen.spamhaus.org has address 127.0.0.2
130.119.180.199.zen.spamhaus.org has address 127.0.0.11
```

A listed domain or address results in results of the form 127.0.0.*, while clean domains/addresses return a "not found" status.

Comment: if you're updating the answer, make it a community wiki. Otherwise make your own answer (or community wiki answer) to gather the edits. But don't do radical changes on someone else's answer, even if it's your question!

Comment: I'm not sure how to turn the answer into a community wiki. I checked the checkmark, which is now green for me.

Answer (score 1):

This C++ code works safe and fast:

```
char *server = "some.spammer.org"; // or Ip address
BYTE ResType = 0;
HOSTENT *pHost = gethostbyname(server);
if (pHost)
{
    char query[80];
    BYTE *ip = (BYTE *)pHost->h_addr;
    sprintf(query, "%u.%u.%u.%u.zen.spamhaus.org", ip[3], ip[2], ip[1], p[0]);
    pHost = gethostbyname(query);
    if (pHost)
    {
        ResType = pHost->h_addr[3];
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the asker's problem, you should [edit] it to explain how it works.